# Slimファイル内で記述された変数をsassに渡す方法について

Tags: sass, slim-lang

はじめまして。

Slim + sass + middlemanでプロトタイピングをしています。
Slimファイル内でSass・SCSSを記述する際に、Slim内で定義した変数をSass・SCSSで参照する方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。
※Hamlでは同様のことができたような記憶があるのですが…

例として、下記のようなことを実現したいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

### sample.slim

---

```
//slimで変数を定義
- height = 177.0
- width = Time.now.min
.rectangle

sass:
  .rectangle
    //sassで変数を呼び出し
    height: $height
    width: $width
```

Answer (score 1):

出来ないと思います。
slimで完結するしか無いのでは？

[slim]

```
- height = 177.0
- width = Time.now.min

.rectangle style="height: #{height}; width: #{width};"
```

もしくは、jQueryを使うとか

[slim + jQuery]

```
- height = 177.0
- width = Time.now.min

.rectangle

javascript:
  $(document).ready(function(){$('.rectangle').css({'height': #{height}, 'width': #{width}});});
```

しかし、上記の例でmiddlemanだと、widthはビルドした時の値なので、動的に変化するわけでもなく、slimを使ってTime.now.minしていること自体に疑問を感じます。時刻に応じて、動的にwidthの値を変えたいのであれば、widthの値算出をJavaScriptでやる必要があるのでは？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
slimだとできないのですね…。

>動的に変化するわけでもなく、slimを使ってTime.now.minしていること自体に疑問を感じます

こちらについて、本当にやりたかったのは、時計を作ることでした。

slim側で時刻を取得して、その時刻から時計針の初期角度を計算し、
Sassに渡して

    0% transform:rotate(#{$hourDeg}deg)
    100% transform:rotate(#{$hourDeg+360}deg)

というようなCSS animationを実現したかったのです…。